# How $10 +2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{10}+2 > 17$ becomes $2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{10} > 5$ due to theorem $3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm reading Kazarinoff's *Analytic inequalities*. He gives the theorem 3 and 6:

- If $a>b$ and $c>d$ then $a+c> b+d$.
- If $a>b>0$, then $a^{\frac{p}{q}}> b^{\frac{p}{q}}$.

There is an exercise a little bit further: Show that $\sqrt{10}+\sqrt{2}> \sqrt{17}$.

And the solution goes as following:

$$10 +2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{10}+2 > 17\tag{$\text{Theorem 6}$}$$

$$2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{10} > 5\tag{$\text{Theorem 3}$}$$

How is subtracting from both sides a consequence of theorem $3$ (Supposing that this is what is being done)? I took:

$$12 +2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{10} > 17$$

Then $12$ or $2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{10}$ might be $a$ or $c$ and writing $17$ as $12+5$, I'd have:

$$12 +2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{10} > 12+5$$

If $a=12$, then by theorem $3$, $b=5$ to achieve $12>5$ according to the theorem, $c=2\sqrt{2} \sqrt{10}$, $d=12$ but to use the theorem, shouldn't $2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{10}>12$? Also, I could choose $a=2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{10}$ but the only reasonable choice for $c$ would be $5$ and I'd have to have $12>12$.

I looked at Wikipedia and found the following:

> [image]
>   Which seems natural (and I am acquainted with its existence), but I'm a bit confused at how he deduced that from theorem $3$.

I am aware that perhaps, he deduced something  that looks like a subtraction from both sides but is quite different, but I couldn't imagine more and all my experiments failed.

Comment: Are you quite sure that $c>d$ is intended in the statement of Theorem 3? it holds with equality too.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Yes. I was thinking exactly about that. If the statement was $c\geq d$, it would work. But take a look at the book, page 3. PDF page 16: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~morrow/334_16/kazarinoff.pdf

Comment: Theorem 3 can be a consequence of $a=80$, $b=25$, $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{1}{2}$ and 
if $a>b>0$ then $a^\frac{p}{q}>b^\frac{p}{q}$

Comment: @A.Γ. But doesn't it gives you $-12 > -12$?

Comment: @AskYourself Yes, I already noticed that $c>d$ was the assumption.

Comment: book bad, change book ?

Answer (score 1):

It does not follow directly from Theorem 3, but one can make a corollary:

> $a>b$ $\implies$ $a+c>b+c$

*Proof*: By Definition 1, p. 2, $a>b$ means $a=b+h$, $h>0$. As $h/2>0$ too (by Theorem 4 that says $a>b$, $c>0$ $\implies$ $a/c>b/c$), the same definition gives that $a>b+h/2$. Now take $c$ and $d=c-h/2$. We have $c>d$, then by Theorem 3 
$$
a+c>b+h/2+d=b+c.
$$